# json alike objects in c

Tags: c, object

I have a background in javascript and php but and I'm currently trying to learn C however I've hit a bit of a snag, in both those languages there are objects

```
$obj = new stdClass(); || const obj = {};
```

however I've been unable to find something simulair in C, is there no such thing or am I just looking in the wrong place?

Or is there perhaps a better way to do things like this in C?

Ok I think I got the answer from Cody Gray but just to clearify a bit for everyone:

I Javascript you could do something like:

```
const person = {
  name: "Donald Duck",
  age: 82,
  location: "Duckburg",
};

console.log(person.name, person.age, person.location);
```

in php you would do something like

```
$person = new stdClass();

$person->name = "Donald Duck";
$person->age = 82;
$person->location ="Duckburg";

echo $person->name . " " . $person->age . " " . $person->location
```

my question is if/how you could do this in C

Comment: "*things like this*" like *what*, please?

Comment: C doesn't have "objects", it isn't an object-oriented language. Rather, it is a *procedural* programming language. (Although you can kind of simulate objects with the use of `struct`s, it isn't really designed for this and you should become familiar with the C paradigms first.)

Comment: Reading in a json-like object in C means dynamically constructing the object, actually just what javascript does too but in javascript you don't "see" it. With "dynamically constructing" I mean that you have a base data structure that you use to construct components that represent the json elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `structs`. However, C is a completely other beast than those other two languages. First of all, it's statically typed: the type of all your variables and functions must be known at compile time, ***com­plete­ly***. This also means that you cannot just go ahead and use an "object" and fill it with arbitrary many fields like in JS:

```
var person = {};
person.name = "Donald Duck";
person.age  = 82;              // I'm sure that Donald is always depicted younger
person.localtion = "Duckburg"; // woo hoo
```

Later, you may decide that a `person` (or rather `duck`) should also have a size:

```
person.size = 9001;
```

That's not possible in C, where, when you define a structure, you limit yourself to the fields in the structure, and **only** those fields:

```
struct person {
    const char * name;
    int          age;
    const char * location;
};
```

You can then start to create your actual persons:

```
struct person donald;

donald.name     = "Donald Duck";
donald.age      = 82;
donald.location = "Uncle Scrooge's Money Bin";
```

But if you try to add `donald.size` now you **will** get yelled at by the compiler.

That being said, C works **so** different on **so** many levels, it's going to be a wild ride. For example, you cannot go ahead and use `"Donald" + "Duck"` or `"Donald "` . "Duck"`. There is no string concatenation operator. You have to do things by hand, manage memory yourself, and keep many things in mind.

Depending on how you want to use the language, you might want to start with C++ and then delve into its belly where C still lingers. Because C does not have objects. C++ does. But keep in mind that while most C programs can be compiled in C++, they're somewhat distinct languages.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have "objects", as it is a *procedural* programming language, rather than an object-oriented one.

However, it *does* have a way to group related data, and that is via a structure (`struct` keyword). This is what you may know more generically as a user-defined type. It isn't quite the same as a "class" or "object" in other languages, because it doesn't have any associated member functions (at least, not without a *lot* of crazy trickery that isn't really part of the language and certainly isn't idiomatic), but it is very handy nevertheless.

The syntax would be something like:

```
struct Person
{
    char name[100];
    int  age;
    char location[100];
};
```

Then, in your code, you would just do:

```
struct Person donaldDuck = { "Donald Duck", 82, "Duckburg" };


printf("Name: %s\nAge: %d\nLocation: %s\n",
       donaldDuck.name,
       donaldDuck.age,
       donaldDuck.location);
```

Notice that fields of the struct are accessed using the `.` operator, like many other languages.

[See it online](http://ideone.com/7ZRQxg)!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plethora of C libraries on the web.
For example, take a look at 
https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON/blob/master/README.md

Comment: there are, however for me at least that is not the correct way to learn how to do it yourself and trying to backwards engineer something that I have yet to fully understand is not something I feel like I can handle at least not at the moment